# how to I make HTTPS url/link work to my amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've set up my website via amazon ec2 instance, I've propagated my third party domain using route 53, all is working fine for HTTP traffic, in security policies I've allowed https, and in amazon certificate manager I've set up a certificate for both mydomain.com and [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)

It seems to have been issued, but the https URL is not going to my domain. Is there anything I'm missing?

[picture of amazon certificate manager showing issued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcw7E.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS ACM certificates can only be used on:

- load balancers,
- CloudFront distribution,
- API Gateway, and
- Nitro Enclaves.

This means it **can't be used** on instances (not in enclaves).

Thus, if you don't want to use any of the above options, you have to get a SSL certificate from a **third party**. A popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ with https://certbot.eff.org/ and setup it on your instance, using for example, nginx.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  followed the steps, its now working